# Calculate p-value for linear regression

Tags: mysql, linear-regression, mysql-8.0, p-value

I'm trying to run a linear regression using MySQL. The useful article [here](http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-linear-regression.html) has a solution however I'd also like to calculate the p-value to see if the result is significant.

Assuming I use the following SQL:

```
select slope, 
       y_bar_max - x_bar_max * slope as intercept 
from (
    select sum((x - x_bar) * (y - y_bar)) / sum((x - x_bar) * (x - x_bar)) as slope,
           max(x_bar) as x_bar_max,
           max(y_bar) as y_bar_max    
    from (
        select x, avg(x) over () as x_bar,
               y, avg(y) over () as y_bar
        from ols) s;
)
```

What would be the SQL calculate a p-value?

Disclaimer: I'm clearly not a stats expert and only loosely understand the principle of the p-value...

Some basic table data:

```
CREATE TABLE `example_table` (
  `id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` int NOT NULL,
  `y` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_`)
);
INSERT INTO `example_table` VALUES (1,1,2),(2,2,1),(3,1,3),(4,2,1);
```